# Unable to add custom behavior to all repositories - IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type

Tags: java, spring, repository, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've implemented my code as described here 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories
, but something is wrong and it does not work.

Always getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personSharedRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class Person
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:102)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class Person
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:219)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:65)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:149)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:88)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:68)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:158)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
... 43 more
```

My classes are below.
The interface declaring custom behaviour:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface SharedRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {

    void sharedMethod();

}
```

Custom repository base class:

```
public class SharedRepositoryImpl <T, ID extends Serializable> extends QueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID> implements SharedRepository<T, ID> {

    private static final EntityPathResolver DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE;

    private final EntityPath<T> path;
    private final PathBuilder<T> builder;
    private final Querydsl querydsl;

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public SharedRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        this(entityInformation, entityManager, DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER);
    }

    public SharedRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager, EntityPathResolver resolver) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager, resolver);
        this.path = resolver.createPath(entityInformation.getJavaType());
        this.builder = new PathBuilder<T>(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
        this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, builder);
    }

    @Override
    public void sharedMethod() {
        System.out.println("HELLO WORLD!");
    }
}
```

Custom repository factory bean:

```
public class SharedRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
    extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {

    return new SharedRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
}

private static class SharedRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public SharedRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityManager);

        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
        JpaEntityInformation<T, Serializable> entityInformation = (JpaEntityInformation<T, Serializable>) getEntityInformation(metadata.getDomainType());
        return new SharedRepositoryImpl<T, Serializable>(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }

    protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

        // The RepositoryMetadata can be safely ignored, it is used by the JpaRepositoryFactory
        //to check for QueryDslJpaRepository's which is out of scope.
        return SharedRepository.class;
    }
}
```

}

Configuration:

```
@ComponentScan (basePackageClasses = {Person.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {PersonSharedRepository.class}, repositoryFactoryBeanClass = SharedRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class JpaConfiguration {
}
```

My repository:

```
public interface PersonSharedRepository extends SharedRepository<Person, Long> {

    Person findByFirstName(@Param("firstName") String firstName);

}
```

And finally my unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JpaConfiguration.class, RestConfig.class})
public class PersonSharedRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    PersonSharedRepository repository;
    /**
     * Test invocation of custom method.
     */
    @Test
    public void testRepo() {

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName("john");
        person.setLastName("smith");
        Person person1 = repository.save(person);
        repository.sharedMethod();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The Person class is annotated correctly:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

**BUT** I updated the JpaConfig with LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:

```
@ComponentScan (basePackageClasses = {Person.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {PersonSharedRepository.class},
        includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = {PersonSharedRepository.class}, type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE),
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = SharedRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {

        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("domain");  //the package to my Person class
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return (EntityManagerFactory) factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException {

        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }
```

I got the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public     org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager   config.JpaConfiguration.transactionManager() throws java.sql.SQLException] threw exception; nested  exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aab5dbd5 cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aab5dbd5 cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
at config.JpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6a249d18.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
at config.JpaConfiguration.transactionManager(JpaConfiguration.java:75)
at config.JpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6a249d18.CGLIB$transactionManager$3(<generated>)
at config.JpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6a249d18$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e4d66840.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
at config.JpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6a249d18.transactionManager(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
... 46 more
```

Comment: Please show Person class. Is it JPA-enabled (does it have Entity annotation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in java config. I fixed it by changing the method signature, I added the entitymanager as a method parameter instead of a method call.

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) throws SQLException {

    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return txManager;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it when I created my xml config file and added a transaction manager bean to it.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Does anybody has an idea why the java and xml configurations are not identical?